# running my JDBC application in other systems

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I created a JDBC application  using mysql5.5.14 .
I want to run it on other systems without mysql5.5.14.(but having java)
Is thee any way i can install(and configure) mysql5.5.14 on other systems via my application.

Comment: To install MySQL on another system you must usually have access to this system with root/admin priveleges. Installing mysql via java looks hard for me.

Comment: Do you want to connect to the already existing remote database or do you want to roll a new database?

Comment: anyways my app is a small one ...i thought ill just use derby embedded database.Thank you all for your help...i'll try those out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but if you mean "configure" as in "create the same database tables and views", you can use something like Liquibase.

If you want to keep using JDBC but with another database system at the backend, you can just pass the JDBC driver's class name to the program through a configuration file and load the driver using

```
Class.forName(jdbcDriver)
```

when you start up your application.

HTH

Raku